# Why would an Xpage launched from an embedded view act differently than the same one launched from a regular view?

Tags: xpages

I have a contact xpage with an embedded view that let's the user add multiple addresses.  The embedded view is contained in a custom control that has two buttons: one to add a new address and one to delete the selected addresses.  When I run it, it displays the addresses associated with that contact in the embedded view, but when I try to open one of the addresses, it displays the address xpage for a new address instead of the address that was selected. If I open an xpage that contains just the custom control for that embedded view and select an address, it opens the address xpage with the data of the address chosen.

The "Add New Address" button is a simple action the just opens the document, but when it's clicked in the embedded view it acts like New Document is the option, whereas it opens correctly from a regular view.

I thought maybe the program was getting confused with the data sources, but it's uses the right data source, it's just using it incorrectly.

Any ideas?

MJ

Comment: maybe you have used cut and paste to add the embedded view?

Comment: Nope, it was created from scratch.  The same custom control is being used both ways.  Only difference is one xpage has the custom control on the page in a tabbed panel and the other xpage has just the custom control on the xpage.

Comment: The custom control has the first column displayed as links.  If you select one of the links from the xpage where the view is in the tabbed panel, you get the xpage with all the fields blank.  If you select on of the links from the xpage that contains only the view, you get the xpage with the data from the link selected.